# How can I use gulp to create Typescript sourcemaps in different files rather than inside the javascript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp

I have a project where I am using gulp. I would like to have the typescript files converted to javascript and to have source maps also. Here is what I have right now:

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())     
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))    
});
```

This works partly but the sourcemaps all appear inside the javascript. Can anyone tell me how I can make it so that it creates a sourcemap file for each javascript rather than have the map inside?

Answer (score 17):

You are writing your `sourcemaps.write()` to be inline.

From the [gulp-sourcemaps repo](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps)

> To write external source map files, pass a path relative to the
>   destination to sourcemaps.write().

Should be -

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))    
});
```

See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I tried this. It added comments like //# sourceMappingURL=../../../maps/access/controllers/HomeController.js.map to my files but there's no map file produced.

Comment: Oh duh - the docs show the plugins go after the `sourcemaps.init`.  Run `typescript()` post `init`.

Comment: @Alan You can use `sourcemaps.write(".")` to write source maps to `.js.map` files instead of inlining them. Ref: [github](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/201)

Comment: The `sourcemaps.init()` call was what I missed. But for some reason my code worked without this line for some time, so weird.